# Place <div> 'under' drop shadow

Tags: z-index, css

I have a black navigation bar (`bar`) and a vertical white page (`page`).

The `page` is supposed to run from to to bottom and look like it just comes out from right under the `bar`. The `bar` has a drop shadow which should obviously be 'on' the `page` - like this:

[image: page beneath]

The problem with this is that the `page` needs a `z-index` of **-1** to look like this (both have a fixed or relative positioning) - and this means (at least in Chrome) that I can't select or click anything on the `page`.

When I assign a `z-index` of **2** (bar being **10**) it obviously doesn't work anymore:

[image: page on top]

Yet at least I can click the `page`'s elements.

**How can I achive the correct look while still being able to click/select elements?**

Comment: shame on me: I forgot the 'position: relative' on the header, now it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could set `box-shadow: inset (...)` to `page`.
http://jsfiddle.net/seler/fP2Gx/

 or: http://jsfiddle.net/seler/fP2Gx/12/

Comment: i'm not sure if this is what you want. give us code sample.

there may be some background issues and others.